# Disabling Auto Gamma Adjustment in CIFilter in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics

It seems that the outputImage of CIFilter is always gamma-adjusted, the adjustment value could be 1.8 or 2.2 depending on some user preference. For a CIColorMatrix filter, an inputImage in constant white with 0.5 scale matrix would produce an outputImage in 173/255 (for 1.8) or 188/255 (for 2.2) for all components (they are picked with PaintBrush), but 128/255 should be expected

So, how do we disable the auto gamma adjustment so the math is back to linear?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and I used the following workaround sequence :

- using CIGammaAdjust, with inputPower = 1/2.2
- applying my CIColorMatrix
- using CIGammaAdjust with inputPower = 2.2

Based on my tests CIFilters are in effect compensating twice : before processing and after processing, this explains my 2 CIGammaAdjust filters.